# Has anyone worked with www.atript.com?

Tags: affiliate, sem

I want to use atript.com for further monetization of my page. Has anyone worked with it yet?
Is it secure and how long does the integration take and how can I see whether the container is working?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I integrated atript already on a couple of websites. I never really had security issues. The integration is super simple, usually took me like 5 minutes. Wherever I could I tried installing it using the Google tag manager. 
To check whether the container is working just open your browser's developer console. If you see “loading tripts…” in the console the atript.com container is active and working.[image: Loading Tripts...]